# How to test metadata using XMLpath in RESTasured

Tags: xml, odata, metadata, rest-assured

I want to know how to test metadata with XMLpath using RESTassured . I am trying to test an OData service and read each detail in metadata. I can read Json response. But can't sort out a clear way to read metadata. Also I want to know what is identified as nodes in metadata.

Comment: It would help to post an example of the XML that you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Here are cucumber rest-assured steps for parsing a simple OData XML document.

```
package steps;

import java.util.List;

import com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;
import com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.element.Node;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

import static com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath.*;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class ODataSteps {
    String sampleXml = "";

    @Given("^I have a simple service document$")
    public void i_have_a_simple_service_document() {
        sampleXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>" +
            "<service xml:base=\"http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/\"" +
            "         xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"" +
            "         xmlns:app=\"http://www.w3.org/2007/app\"" +
            "         xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2007/app\">" +
            "  <workspace>" +
            "    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>" +
            "    <collection href=\"Products\">" + 
            "      <atom:title>Products</atom:title>" +
            "    </collection>" +
            "    <collection href=\"Categories\">" +
            "      <atom:title>Categories</atom:title>" + 
            "    </collection>" +
            "    <collection href=\"Suppliers\">" +
            "      <atom:title>Suppliers</atom:title>" +
            "    </collection>" +
            "  </workspace>" +
            "</service>";
    }

    @When("^I search for available collections I find \"(\\d+)\"$")
    public void i_search_for_available_collections_i_find(int expectedNumCategories) {
        XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(sampleXml);
        final List<Node> collections = xmlPath.getList("service.workspace.collection", Node.class);
        assertThat(collections.size(), equalTo(expectedNumCategories));

        final List<String> collectionsStr = given(sampleXml).getList("service.workspace.collection.findAll {it.title.text()}", String.class);
        assertThat(collectionsStr, hasItems("Products", "Categories", "Suppliers"));
    }

}
```

The cucumber-jvm feature file that invokes the above looks like this:

```
@odata
Feature: Demonstrate ability to test OData Service Documents
  The Open Data Protocol (OData) enables the creation of HTTP-based data 
  services, which allow resources identified using Uniform Resource 
  Identifiers (URIs) and defined in an abstract data model, to be    published 
  and edited by Web clients using simple HTTP messages.

@api
Scenario: Parse a canned OData Service document
  Given I have a simple service document
  When I search for available collections I find "3"
```

Comment: Thak you for your help